# Docx4j corrupts word file when editing document.xml

Tags: java, ms-word, docx4j

I know this exact question has been asked before and has a solution, but it makes no sense to me. When replacing a tag in my document.xml, the .docx document gets corrupted. I can open it normally with Wordpad but Word wont do it. I tried changing permissions and adding new trusted locations to word but nothing changes.

[This is what Word throws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI2AU.png)

```
    File src = new File(testDocx);

    File doc = new File(test);
    Files.copy(src.toPath(), doc.toPath());


    WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage =
            Docx4J.load(doc);

    MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordprocessingMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

    String xpath = "//w:p";
    List<Object> list = mainDocumentPart.getJAXBNodesViaXPath(xpath, false);
    ObjectFactory objectFactory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();

    for (Object o: list) {
        o = (P) o;
        String comp = o.toString();

        switch (comp) {
            case "<#ATRIBUTI>":
                ((P) o).getContent().set(0, null);
                Tbl table = objectFactory.createTbl();
                for (Object name: product.getAttributes().keySet()) {
                    String key = name.toString();
                    String val = product.getAttributes().get(key);

                    Tr row = objectFactory.createTr();

                    Tc keyCell = objectFactory.createTc();
                    Text keyText = objectFactory.createText();
                    keyText.setValue(key);
                    keyCell.getContent().add(keyText);
                    row.getContent().add(keyCell);

                    Tc valCell = objectFactory.createTc();
                    Text valText = objectFactory.createText();
                    valText.setValue(val);
                    valCell.getContent().add(valText);
                    row.getContent().add(valCell);

                    table.getContent().add(row);
                }
                ((P) o).getContent().set(0, table);
                wordprocessingMLPackage.save(doc);
```

Comment: What are your values for key and val?

Comment: @JasonPlutext They're always strings. It has just occured to me that the encoding might be the problem though. I'll give try actually setting it.

Comment: Do the strings ever contain xml reserved characters?